# How to make discord js ( V12 ) detect how many characters are in message

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was making discord bot and level system for it, it succeeded, but at the moment it adds XP for a message, I want to make it add XP per character amount in the message.

I have also made it have progressive XP system, aka bigger level you have, more XP you have to get to get next level.

And another one question, is it possible to make the bot somehow detect spam? For example if someone just says "AAAAAAA" then the person won't recieve XP for that.

```
 const addXp = async(profilepic, username, userObject, guildId, userId, xpToAdd, message) => {
     await mongo().then(async mongoose => {
         try {
        const result = await xpShema.findOneAndUpdate({
                 guildId,
                 userId,
                 username,
                 profilepic                       
             }, {
                 guildId,
                 userId,
                 username,
                 profilepic,
                 $inc: {
                     xp: xpToAdd,
                     level: 0
                 }
             }, {
                 upsert: true,
                 new: true
             }).catch(err => console.log(err));
                         
             var { xp, level } = result;
             const needed = getNeededXP(level)

             if(xp >= needed) {
                ++level;
                xp -= needed; 
 
                message.reply(`You are now **level ${level}** with **${xp} xp**! You now need **${getNeededXP (level)} XP** to level up again!`)
 
                await xpShema.updateOne({
                    guildId,
                    userId,
                    username,
                    profilepic
                }, {
                    level,
                    xp
                }).catch(err => console.log(err));
             }
 
             if(message.content.toLowerCase() === '!level') {
               const embedgoesbrr = new discord.MessageEmbed()
               embedgoesbrr.setColor("#fcfdff")
               embedgoesbrr.setTitle('Level!')
               embedgoesbrr.setFooter('If you need support move to #server-support and write "!ticket"')
               embedgoesbrr.setTimestamp()
               embedgoesbrr.setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/570312043949981710/745387739285029010/CrysisOfClans_2.png")
               embedgoesbrr.setDescription(`Your level is ${level} and you have ${xp} xp, you need ${getNeededXP (level)} to reach level ${level + 1}`);
               message.channel.sendEmbed(embedgoesbrr)
             }
 
             console.log("Logged into Mongo");
         } catch(err) {
             console.log(err)
         }               
     })      
 }

// This part makes bot add XP ( in my case 5XP per message )

 let user = message.author;

     if(!message.author.bot) {
        addXp(message.author.avatarURL({format: "png", dynamic: "false"}), message.author.tag, user, message.guild.id, user.id, 5, message);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If discord returns `message` as a string primitive you can use `String.length` property to grab the number of characters in the string, then apply a coefficient to add XP relative to that number.

```
let expGain = message.content.length * expModifier
```

or add logic (probably would need to be pretty robust and a whole other conversation to avoid spam levelling). A hard-coded example would be:

```
expGain !== "AAAAAAAAA" ? message.length * expModifier : "Nice Try!"
```

With a function that tests for spam:

```
function spamCheck(msg){
  ...
  // some logic that returns true if spam, false if normal
  ...
}

if (spamCheck(message)) {
  sendMessage("Nice Try!")
}
else {
  let expGain = message * expModifier
}
```